# AWS https certificate additional certification required

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-certificate-manager

I am trying to setup a https end point for my rest service in AWS.

I need to setup a certificate for the https protocol.

I setup with the following detail:

[image]

where mytestenv-env is the environment that I created in AWS.

But this is the error message that I get when I tried to create the certificate where it says "Additional verification required to request certificate for one or more domain names in this request."

Looks like I need to do some verification, but where?

thanks.

[image]

Comment: In the first screenshot, you have opted to use DNS validation, so you need to go to Route 53 and perform the validation. if you don't have access to Rout53 then you should use Email validation. Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: Did you try to go ahead with email validation?

Comment: So, you could probably tell, I am new on AWS. So I am just using the elasticbeanstalk environment from aws (mytestenvir-env.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com). I don't have any custom domain names, Do I still neeed to use Route 53? I also tried using email validation. Is this the email address that you used to get AWS services? I didn't get any email notifications there. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get ssl certificate for aws provided domain for your ELB. You can only get ssl certificate for your OWN domain which you bought or at least fully control.

Comment: Hi Marcin, so it's not possible to setup https end points in AWS using ELB?

Comment: @qed59 Of course its possible, but you have to have your OWN domain, e.g. `myapp.xyz`. You can buy it in route53 or any other domain registrar.